# How we get value of current url in protractor

Tags: protractor

I am using protractor 5.2.2. In our requirement, we need value of current url and according to the Url, I need to do some particular actions.I have used below code for that.

```
var urlvalue= browser.getCurrentUrl();
if(urlvalue.startsWith("https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier")){
  ----
}else{
---
}
```

But it gives an error

```
TypeError: urlvalue.startsWith is not a function
```

How can i get Url value here.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The method I use to check if url contains a certain string is with `indexOf` (if it doesn't, the value of `indexOf` is -1).

```
    browser.getCurrentUrl().then( function( url ) {
  if(url.indexOf("https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier")>-1){
    - - - -
  }
  else{
    - - - -
  }
})
```